# How to reinstall of Android on a tablet?

Tags: tablet, operating-system

I am learning Android app development. I wanted a cheap tablet to test how apps looked on tablet as opposed to mobile. I bought a cheap tablet from wish.com.

OK, stop laughing at that last bit... it seemed like a good idea at the time.

What I received (and was subsequently refunded for), was a tablet that seems to be locked to only the Chinese app store that was already installed. I can't install Google Play (I have tried multiple versions), and therefore it is pretty useless to me.

I did manage to install a version of Droid Info which pulled up various data, build number, kernel, Android version etc.

Is there any way I can use that data to find, and flash the device with a clean version of Android that might work?

This thing is good for nothing but the bin, otherwise.

Appreciate any suggestions.

UPDATE ---

Screenshot below of what is displayed on the 'about this device' section of the OS settings. Hope that sheds some light on the device model.

[image: Device Details screenshot]

Comment: It depends a lot on the tablet model. Can you dig it somewhere? Probably there is some "about this tablet" or similar in the system settings.

Comment: Btw, your case is absolutely not so bad, although rooting / reinstalling the Android will take some learn and work. But also learning the app development will be. If you can not root it, and do not brick it, you can sell it to others - maybe its worth is zero for you, but it might be pretty useful for a Chinese. The bad thing is only that these cheap chinese phones/tablets are mostly unsupported by the alternate Android versions (LineageOS).

Comment: @alecxs I think it does not - instead of a generic answer, it would be **much better** to have a google-searchable repository for all the Android-capable phones/tablets with a how-to-root tutorial.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica not worth it. broad question, broad answer. no guesswork

Comment: @alecxs If the OP writes his exact model, then it is not broad. If he does not, I agree in this. In the general case, I think getting a good place in the google search for "how to root <model name>" queries would be extremely useful. Currently these questions are answered by the *-developers. That site... well they would imho profit a lot if the posts there would be editable/downvotable.

Comment: Not all manufacturers provide stock ROM (especially for unpopular/unrecognized brands). If there's no stock ROM, then another workaround is custom ROM, but the problem is that there's no generic Android ROM that can be installed on any device. Instead, every custom ROM has to be built specifically for the specific model, so without any device/build information, we can't help either...